# How can I get the value of all the selected cells in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, multi-select

I have a DataGridView that has MultiSelect = true. After the user selects different cells from different rows how can I get the value of all the selected cells?

Comment: A DataGrid (mentioned in your question body) is not the same as a DataGridView (in the title and tags).

Comment: True... My Bad. I just edited it..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can iterate over [SelectedCells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx).

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
{
    MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());
}
```

You asked only for the value, but you probably also want to know the row and the column of the cell otherwise the value could be meaningless. You can access these also on the cell object.

Answer (score 4):

foreach -

```
DataGrid.SelectedCells
```

More info on the SelectedCells Property can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx

The SelectedCells collection is inefficient with large selections in DataGridView.  There is a method you can use to get the count of the selected cells.  iterate based on that and it'll be faster.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.GetCellCount(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewElementStates.Selected); i++)
{
    string val = grid.SelectedCells[i].Value;
}
```

Comment: Can you write a example of the for each?

Comment: Added code example for you.  Be sure to look at the GetCellCount method.  It'll be important to know.